# Searching for a row in a table that matches all corresponding values in a different table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to compare values from another table and column and put them in a seperate column in a different table, and I'm lost.

table1 has 2 columns OLD and NEW

table2 also has an OLD and NEW but new is blank.

I'm trying to search table1 by the OLD column and get the corresponding NEW value into the NEW column in table 2.

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table2
join table1 on table2.old = table1.old
set table2.`new` = table1.`new`
```